# Reading a TableRow cell value and returning an integer

Tags: android, integer, tablelayout, tablerow

Basically I have a TableLayout with several TableRows, each containg 5 cells (Name, Price, Count, IncreaseButton, DecreaseButton), and then I have written a function to return the price of a certain row, but I keep getting an exception.

This is the code:

```
private int getRowPrice(View target) //target is a Button
{
    TableRow row = (TableRow) target.getParent();
    TextView priceCell = (TextView) row.getChildAt(1);

    String price = priceCell.getText().toString();

    //The cell text may start with $ or another currency
    if (price.startsWith(getString(R.string.currency))) 
    {
        price = price.substring(getString(R.string.currency).length()).toString();
    }

    return Integer.getInteger(price); //Here I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException"
}
```

If I Log.d() the price it outputs the correct value, and if I try to return getInteger("10") that works fine, also the debugger classifies 'price' as a string. So I must admit I have no idea why this error keeps occuring.

And please let me know if there is a better, less-error-prone way to get a cell of a certain row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Integer.valueOf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [Integer.getInteger()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger%28java.lang.String%29). If you look at the API docs for Integer.getInteger() you'll see that it "Returns the Integer value of the system property identified by the given string". The method name is a bit misleading.